# Using async/await correctly in the context of token validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await, google-signin

I'm building an Express.js backend for a website validating users using Google Sign-in.

And, I'm trying to create a RESTful API call which:

1. Takes in an IDtoken.
2. Validates that token using Google's OAuth2 Library.
3. Checks to see if a user is in a MongoDB Collection and then:
4. Either sends back the access token if true, or returns nothing if false.

This is what I have so far...

The post request:

```
//recieve token id from frontend, verify it, and send session back in response
router.post('/google', (req, res) => {
  const idToken = req.body.tokenID;
  const accessToken = req.body.accessToken;
  const client = new OAuth2Client(keys.google.clientID);

  const session = verify(idToken, accessToken, client).catch(console.error);
  console.log('Session: ', session)
  return res.send(session);
});
```

verify() :

```
//verify token
async function verify(idToken, accessToken, client) {

  const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
    idToken: idToken,
    audience: keys.google.clientID,
  });

  const payload = ticket.getPayload();
  const email = payload['email'];

  if (findUser(email)) {
     return {
      email: email,
      accessToken: accessToken
    };
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

findUser() :

```
//find user
function findUser(email) {

  User.find({email: email}, (error, user) => {
    if(error) {
      console.log(error);
      return false;
    } else if (user.length === 0) {
      console.log('this user is not in the database');
      return false;
    } else {
      console.log('this user is in the database');
      return true;
    }
  });
}
```

For an output regardless of whether the user is in the DB or not I always get:

```
Session:  Promise { <pending> }
this user is in the database
```

or

```
Session:  Promise { <pending> }
this user is not in the database
```

I know that since verify() is an async function I need to get it to resolve its promise before assigning it to a variable, but I'm at a loss for how to do it correctly, and unfortunately, I can't make verify() into a synchronous function as then it does not create the ticket object correctly before calling getPayload() from Google's Library.

Any ideas for how to make all of this happen in the correct order?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try:

```
//recieve token id from frontend, verify it, and send session back in response
router.post('/google', async (req, res) => {
  const idToken = req.body.tokenID;
  const accessToken = req.body.accessToken;
  const client = new OAuth2Client(keys.google.clientID);

  const session = await verify(idToken, accessToken, client).catch(console.error);
  console.log('Session: ', session)
  return res.send(session);
});
```

**Update** - 
Find User:

```
//find user
async function findUser(email) {

  const user = await User.find({email: email}, (error, user) => {
    if(error) {
      console.log(error);
      return false;
    } else if (user.length === 0) {
      console.log('this user is not in the database');
      return false;
    } else {
      console.log('this user is in the database');
      return true;
    }
  });
 return user;
}
```

Comment: When I do that the variable "session" is set to null every time now. So, it resolves, but it seems like it never waits for findUser() now?

Comment: Okay - lemme take a look at the findUseR()

Comment: I've added findUser() example - Please note there may be slight syntax error as I've written it on the fly. Let me know how you get on :)

Comment: Progress! the session variable now gets filled with the correct object, but now it never becomes null as it should when a user is not found in the db. I tried setting findUser to return true of false depending on if user.length is greater than 0, as I wasn't sure if returning the user array empty or full would still make if(findUser(email)) true either way, but this didn't seem to have any effect...

Comment: I think I found a work-around. Instead of calling findUser() inside of verify() I moved it to happen after verify() inside the post request. This still requires making both functions async and awaiting their logic, but it's a little easier to follow, and seems to work everytime as expected. Thanks for your time though! I don't think I would have figured it out on my own.

Comment: @Tremarche - your more than welcome. Thats why I love async/await so much purely because it makes code so much easier to read and more 'human-like' in my eyes at least. None of this nested .then() etc. Glad you got it sorted :)